# i have created a form and connected it to mysql and i have added code for validation form but its not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

i have created a registrartion form and connected it to mysql and data is sucessfully entered in tables in database now i want to add validations on form i have a file index.html in which i have a code of body of form and second file is connect.php where i have database connectivity code and validations code now when i run the program i can add data in form and its saved in database but validations code is not working

here is my code

```
<?php
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];

//database Connection


$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'codetodesign');

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {
$stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into registration(firstName, lastName, mail, password, age, gender) 
values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssssi",$firstname, $lastname, $mail, $password, $age, $gender);
    $stmt->execute();
echo "Registration successfully";
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
}

//Validation data

$firstnameErr = $lastnameErr = $mailErr = $passwordErr = $ageErr = $genderErr = "";
$firstname = $lastname = $mail = $password = $age = $gender = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
if (empty($_POST["firstname"])){
    $firstnameErr = "Firstname is required";
} else {
    $firstname = test_input($_POST["firstname"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["lastname"])){
    $lastnameErr = "lastname is required";
} else {
    $lastname = test_input($_POST["lastname"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["mail"])){
    $mailErr = "Mail is required";
} else {
    $mail = test_input($_POST["mail"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["password"])){
    $passwordErr = "Password is required";
} else {
    $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["age"])){
    $ageErr = "Age is required";
} else {
    $age = test_input($_POST["age"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["gender"])){
    $genderErr = "Gender is required";
} else {
    $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
}
}

function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
?>
```

Comment: _**Never ever** ever never_ store passwords in plain text! You should _always_ hash the passwords using [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and only store the hashes. Then you can use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify a password against a hash. Stripping a password from certain characters can drastically weaken the  password. It's also not needed if you just store the hash.

Comment: If you want to add validation, you should validate the data _before_ you insert it so you can reject it (not insert it) if the validation failed.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson mate thanks for the help can you please guide how to validate data because i am very beginner with php and secondly i have my whole data in two different files index.html and connect.php which makes it a bit more diffcult for me anyway can you guide me how can i validate my data mean which function i should use

Comment: Do not use `test_input()` function. It will damage your data.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are enjoying your coding journey. Here I added some modification regarding your asking and approach.

**Modifications:**

- We take an array variable named **errors** where we will store the errors
- If we find any error we will store them in our **errors** variable
- Then we will check the validation before we insert the data into database that errors array is empty or not
- If **errors** is empty we simply store our data into database.
- And if not we will catch all the errors from **errors** variable and will show those errors in our **form(index.php)** file.
- Follow the below codes of two files hope rest of you understand easily.

Good Luck.

**process.php**

```
<?php
    
        //database Connection
        $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'codetodesign');
    
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
    
        //error array
        $errors = array();
        $success = null;
    
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    
            $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
            $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
            $mail = $_POST['mail'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $age = $_POST['age'];
            $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    
    
            if (empty($firstname)){
                $errors['f_name'] = "Firstname is required";
            } else {
                $firstname = test_input($_POST["firstname"]);
            }
    
            if (empty($lastname)){
                $errors['l_name'] = "lastname is required";
            } else {
                $lastname = test_input($_POST["lastname"]); 
            }
    
            if (empty($mail)){
                $errors['mail'] = "Mail is required";
            } else {
                $mail = test_input($_POST["mail"]);
            }
    
            if (empty($password)){
                $errors['password'] = "Password is required";
            } else {
                $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
            }
    
            if (empty($age)){
                $errors['age'] = "Age is required";
            } else {
                $age = test_input($_POST["age"]);
            }
    
            if (empty($gender)){
                $errors['gender'] = "Gender is required";
            } else {
                $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
            }
    
            if(!empty($errors)) {
                $errors['msg'] = "Please fillup the below required fileds";
            } else {
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into registration(firstName, lastName, mail, password, age, gender) 
                    values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                        $stmt->bind_param("sssssi",$firstname, $lastname, $mail, $password, $age, $gender);
                    //$stmt->execute();
                    if($stmt->execute()) {
                        $success = "Registration successfully";
                    }
                $stmt->close();
                $conn->close();
            }
        }
    
        function test_input($data) {
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
            return $data;
        }
    ?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php include('process.php') ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test From</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container col-md-6">
        <h1>Simple Form Registrarion</h1>
        <h5 class="text-success"><?php if($success != null) echo $success; ?>
        <h5 class="text-danger"><?php if(!empty($errors) && !empty($errors['msg'])) echo $errors['msg']; ?></h5>
        <form action="index.php" method="POST">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputfname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" id="exampleInputfname" aria-describedby="fnameHelp" placeholder="Enter First Name">
            <small id="fnameHelp" class="form-text text-danger"><?php if(!empty($errors) && !empty($errors['f_name'])) echo $errors['f_name']; ?></small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputlname">Last Name address</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" id="exampleInputlname" aria-describedby="lnameHelp" placeholder="Enter Last Name">
            <small id="lnameHelp" class="form-text text-danger"><?php if(!empty($errors) && !empty($errors['l_name'])) echo $errors['l_name']; ?></small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" name="mail" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-danger"><?php if(!empty($errors) && !empty($errors['mail'])) echo $errors['mail']; ?></small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" aria-describedby="passHelp">
             <small id="passHelp" class="form-text text-danger"><?php if(!empty($errors) && !empty($errors['password'])) echo $errors['password']; ?></small>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputgender">Gender</label>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" name="gender" value="1" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1" checked>
              <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                Male
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" name="gender" value="2" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios2" value="option2">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
                Female
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" name="gender" value="3" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios2" value="option2">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
                Other
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputage">Age</label>
            <input type="number" name="age" class="form-control" id="exampleInputage" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter age">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-danger"><?php if(!empty($errors) && !empty($errors['age'])) echo $errors['age']; ?></small>
          </div>

          <button type="submit" name="register" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: i had followed the code you gave above, i add 3 more fields in it but now its giving the following error     Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in D:\xampp\htdocs\validationdatabase\wp-content\Validation\connect.php on line 48

Comment: i have checked the whole syntax and code everything is fine but still its giving error

Comment: there is a syntax error, you missed any curly bracket, go throw the line 48 and see where you missed or added extra bracket.